# What is the function of the LockItem attribute in appSettings in App.Config file?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

```
<add key="MaxAllowed" value="90" lockItem="false"/>
```

There is a item called lockItem in my config file? 
MSDN states that "Gets or sets a value indicating whether the element is locked."

What does this mean? Does it mean that if set to true, the configuration won't be changed by editing the config file?

Comment: This might help: http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/planning-for-security/how-to-use-locking-in-iis-configuration

Comment: MSDN, the master of tautology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. The lockitem prevents modification for that node or any child node, if you have nested nodes. There is also LockAllAttributesExcept if you want to lock certain attibutes and not others.